# Mercurial how to create patch for one file in repo

Tags: mercurial, export

I have a file called some/work/file.py in my repo.

I have been working in the repo (on other files too besides file.py) and committing my changes and have gone from revision 20 to 30.

How would I create a patch for only file.py from revisions 20 to 30 without including the other files?

Something like:

```
hg export 20:30 file.py > new.patch
```

Have tried the command but does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hg export` exports individual changesets as separate entities.

If I understand you correctly, you need an answer to the question “What changes were made to `file.c` between revision 20 and revision 30?”, i.e. you need only need one diff file.

Here’s how you can do it:

```
hg diff file.c -r 20:30 > new.diff
```

As a more versatile approach, you can use `-I` (include file pattern) / `-X` (exclude).

Comment: Thank you, I can then apply the diff as a patch with hg import?

Comment: Having updated to rev 20, yes you can. Note this will only update `file.c`, and the changeset history (20:30) will be lost. Care to explain what's the problem you are solving?

Comment: Its fine I just wanted the changes for only file.py to be exported as a patch and not the other changes to other files in the same commit.